# Plotting special function (Debye) in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to plot two functions. One is a Debye function in Matlab multiplied by some other stuff and the other is a regular function. How do I do this? Does Matlab have a toolbox for this?

Comment: what is it that you don't know how to do? Plotting a function? http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/plot.html

Answer (score 1):

If you can calculate the function value `y(x)` at every `x` you want to plot, you simply write `plot(x,y)`, where each entry in the vector `y` corresponds to the entry in `x` for which the function was evaluated. [Here](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/plot.html)'s the help for `plot`.

If you want to plot a function of the form `f(x)==0`, or `f(x,y)=0`, you can alternatively use [EZPLOT](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/ezplot.html). For example, you can write `ezplot('x*sin(x)',-5:0.5:5)`, which will plot the function `x*sin(x)` over the interval `[-5 5]` in steps of `0.5`.

Answer (score 0):

I think he means plotting a Debye function.